# What does Judaism teach about men marrying a widow?

Tags: marriage

I'm interested in what the teaching of the Jewish religion is on a man marrying a woman who had a deceased husband? Is there further considerations in regards to whether the widow has children. A woman cannot with the best intentions be a father to her boys would it be OK to have a second man in her life to help with male role models for her boys?

Would it be better for them to marry or could a living arrangement that is beneficial to both widows be made for the children that does not involve marriage?

Comment: Sefer hachinuch on a Kohen gadol marrying a widow come to mind. And [Pesachim 112a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.112a.14)

Comment: Except for certain rare cases that are extremely unlikely to apply, a man is completely permitted to marry a widow. If the woman was instead divorced, it would be permitted as long as the man is not a kohen (member of the priestly class)

Comment: As life expectancy used to be far shorter, blended families were incredibly common. Talmud's tractate of Kesubos goes through all sorts of cases of a spouse bringing in children from a previous marriage.

Comment: Are the rules the same for women? I know I did specify men in the question. I will post it as a separate question if need be.

Comment: @Shalom could you post some of those cases as an answer. I would love to read a full account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Judaism, the only person who is restricted from marrying a widow is the [high priest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Priest_of_Israel), a position which unfortunately does not exist nowadays.  In fact, many of Judaism's greatest leaders married widows (e.g. [King David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David), [Rava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rava_(amora))).

With regard to blended families, there may be some potential issues regarding *[yichud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yichud)* (isolation with a member of the opposite sex) but there are [generally accepted workarounds in cases of need such as these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yichud#Adopted_children). As always, AYLOR.